# Timestamp for phony target

Tags: makefile, timestamp

How can I add a timestamp in makefile for `.PHONY` targets

```
phony_Target:Real_Target .phony_Target_Token_File
    $(shell run_some_commands)
    touch .phony_Target_Token_File
```

This is the best that I could come up with. But it breaks-down when `.phony_Target_Token_File` does not exists (Since this is viewed as an unmet prerequisite).

Does there exist a smarter way to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to have a phony target only run when "necessary"? Because that's not how phony targets work.

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind. How should `PHONY`s be used?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for an [empty target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Targets)?

Comment: @EtanReisner Empty Target: This is what I am looking for. If I am nitpicking, can I have the token file and target with different names? Preferably hidden

Comment: No. The target must create a file of the same name for make to work properly (assuming you expect to use the empty target as a prerequisite of something else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.PHONY` targets do not honor prerequisite timestamps to determine if they should run. They always run. That is what they are for.<sup>[1](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets)</sup>.

I think perhaps you are looking for an [empty target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Targets) to use as a stamp of some event having taken place.

Comment: What if I want to run the recipe, but the prerequisites run only if necessary? The best that I came up with was to call make recursively for the prerequisite. This is a little suboptimal for debbugging. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Any given target only runs if the rules say it needs to. This can be because it has no prerequisites or because any of the listed prerequisites is "newer" than the target file itself. So if you want to control when things run you need to give them prerequisites that encapsulate the triggers that should cause it to build.